# Jquery easyui autocomplete combobox error

Tags: jquery, combobox

Good morning! I'm using jeasyui framework and I have populated a combobox on a form with JSON with the cities. When I type something to search for the city, I see inconsistent data and the console from an error.

Part of the form:

```
<div style="margin-bottom:20px">
  <input class="easyui-combobox" name="comune_azienda" style="width:100%" data-options="label:'Comune azienda:',labelPosition:'top',required:true,
    url:'getComuni.php',
    method:'get',
    valueField:'id',
    textField:'text',
    panelHeight:'200px'
    ">
</div>
```

Error console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null
at HTMLInputElement.filter (jquery.easyui.min.js:14150)
at jquery.easyui.min.js:13808
at Function.map (jquery.min.js:2)
at _a60 (jquery.easyui.min.js:13801)
at HTMLInputElement.query (jquery.easyui.min.js:14126)
at jquery.easyui.min.js:13370
```

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: You are usying `toLowerCase` on a null var.. Provide a complete code please

Comment: I'm sorry but I can not post the code correctly, I can send it to an email address? Thank you. –

Comment: I can send you the code via email?

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null
```

you are applying `toLowerCase()` function on a variable whose value is `null`

Comment: I'm sorry but I can not post the code correctly, I can send it to an email address?

Thank you.

Comment: I am not able to get you ?

Comment: Sorry I missed the comment.
Thank you.

Comment: Still not able to get you ?

Comment: It is highly possible

Comment: It is highly possible

Comment: And what is the means of this?

Comment: You asked me if I wanted to send the code via email and I confirmed that I would be ideal

Comment: Unfortunately it is not yet resolved, I entered the property editing: false to work around the problem, but it certainly is not beautiful

Comment: Are you on skype?

Comment: Yes, but do not speak English, I always use the automatic translator

Comment: Are you a free lancer?

Comment: Yes I am free lancer

Comment: If you want some help from me ping me on skype. me skype id is: mayank.pandeyz

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but I copied the code from the official website that says anything, the combo is populated correctly but when you typed something generates the error that I sent.

[My page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TVIo.png)

Grazie